# Can you use yourself as DNS?

Tags: debian, networking, dns

I have a local DNS server (PiHole) running inside Docker on a Debian server and I want to configure the host machine to use a static IPv4 address and **itself** as the default DNS, so that queries from there, like on all other network devices, get filtered as well.

If this is possible, maybe should I use

```
iface eno1 inet static
 address         172.28.0.100
 ...
 dns-nameservers 172.28.0.100
```

in `/etc/network/interfaces` or

```
iface eno1 inet static
 address         172.28.0.100
 ...
 dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1
```

aka the *loopback* address?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer:  Yes, a server can be configured to use itself as a DNS resolver.  The configuration can specify the server's loopback or non-loopback IP address (or both), depending on what IP addresses the DNS resolver software is responding on.

The specific answer:  Unfortunately, I don't have experience with Docker enough to say "Yes, it will work" or "No, it won't work" when the DNS resolver is in a Docker container and the network traffic must pass through the Docker daemon to reach the resolver.  I believe it can work fine, I just can't tell you what the configuration should look like.  Don't forget that DNS traffic typically uses UDP as well as TCP.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. As far as I know, Docker will forward the container port to the hosts one (according to my configuartion) and it is possible for me to access a container webpage using the loopback address in a web browser on the host. So I will try both addresses and hope that nothing breaks...